# Left join in R by character type

Tags: r, merge, left-join

am trying to scrape movie sets from 2 different websites

And I want to combine these 2 informations, and tied them up using the movie title name. Here is the first dataset looks like

```
structure(list(event_name = c("maze runner: the death cure", "star wars: the last jedi", 
"spider-man: homecoming"), event_start_time = structure(c(100, 
200, 300), class = "Date"), movie_sold_all = c(100L, 200L, 
300L)), .Names = c("event_name", "event_start_time", "movie_sold_all"
), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is the 2nd dataset that i've scraped

[image]
I have to upload image only since there are >10 columns

What i expect to have is to join the `movie_title` so they it'll incorporate these 2 informations. Basically similar like `left join` in SQL

I've tried `merge( df_bq_movies,movies,by.y="movie_title",all.x = TRUE)`

but the error occurs

`Error in merge.data.frame(df_bq_movies, movies, by.y = "movie_title",  :'by.x' and 'by.y' specify different numbers of columns`

For more information, this is the dimension of the dataset

`data 1 : 605 rows , 3 column
data 2 : 509 rows , 21 column`

Comment: In the first dataset, the name is `event_name`

Comment: try `library(dplyr); left_join(df_bq_movies, movies, by=c("event_name" = "movie_title")`

Comment: @akrun should both dataset have same column name?

Comment: If you check @Stephan's comment, it can be different too.  with `merge`, you need to specify `by.x`

Comment: @akrun have justified both column name to be the same now, all column now into the same dataframe using `left join`, however the 2nd dataframe columns return `NA`. Is it because the character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With merge you have to define both `by.x` and `by.y` if the column name is the same on both datasets you can just use `by` instead.

e.g.

```
 merge( df_bq_movies, movies, by.x = "event_name", by.y = "movie_title")
```

Comment: oh, i should have the same column name then? @snaut

Comment: Nope. Try `by.x = "event_name", by.y = "movie_title"`. Please try to read the function documentations.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, answer is a lot more useful with it.

Comment: This works well, problem why it doesn't work last time is because my first dataset have trailing white space @Aramis7d